# XCode: How to add preprocessor define for a single source file?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4, c-preprocessor

I want to add preprocessor macros for a couple files in my project, but not all the files.  They're 3rd party sources, so I don't want to edit the files, as to avoid merge maintenance hassle when new versions come along.   They happen to interfere with #defines used in other files in the project.

Can XCode 4 compile only certain files with different preprocessor settings than the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your target's **Build Phases** tab, you can set compiler flags for individual files under the **Compile Sources** drop-down. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) provides a lengthy list of options, but they should work equally well for LLVM.

To define a macro, say `FOO`, for a specific file, add the `-D FOO` flag to the "Compiler Flags" entry next to that file.

To un-define a macro `FOO`, add the flag `-U FOO`.